# Extracting Cookie from SOAP Response in SUDS

Tags: python, api, soap, suds

I have to work with an API that has multiple services. All of which require the JSESSION cookie from the authentication one below. When I call the next service however, it doesn't keep the cookie and so rejects them.

```
from suds.client import Client
url = 'http://example/ws/Authenticate?wsdl'
client = Client(url)
result = client.service.connect(username='admin', password='admin')
print client.options.transport.cookiejar

>>> <cookielib.CookieJar[<Cookie JSESSIONID=XXXXXXXXXX for localhost.local/Service/>]>
```

I believe that the way to get it to keep this cookie is to extract it, then provide it as a custom header in the format: -

```
url = 'http://example/ws/dostuffnowloggedin?wsdl' 
client2 = Client(url, headers= { 'Cookie': 'JSESSIONID=value'})
```

But I can't figure out how to do it. I've reviewed the SUDS Docs, URL2LIB and Cookiejar python docs, looked over stack & asked on Reddit. This is the first question I've asked on Stack, I've tried to make it meaningful and specific, but if I've commited a faux par, tell me and I'll do my best to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
from suds.client import Client
url = 'http://example/ws/Authenticate?wsdl'
client = Client(url)
result = client.service.connect(username='admin', password='admin')
url2='url of second service'
client2=Client(url2)
client2.options.transport.cookiejar=client.options.transport.cookiejar
```