# SOAP and persistance

Tags: python, web-services, cookies, soap

I'm writing automated trading bot, using python and suds soap client.

I was wondering if it's possible to increase speed by using persistent SOAP calls.(Like using Session in RESTful services).

Here's what my request looks like:

```
DEBUG:suds.client:sending to (http://api.betdaq.com/v2.0/ReadOnlyService.asmx)
message:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://www.GlobalBettingExchange.com/ExternalAPI/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:None="http://www.GlobalBettingExchange.com/ExternalAPI/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header>
      <ns0:ExternalApiHeader xmlns="http://www.GlobalBettingExchange.com/ExternalAPI/" version="2" languageCode="en" username="****" password="****" applicationIdentifier="***"/>
   </SOAP-ENV:Header>
   <ns1:Body>
      <ns0:GetPrices>
         <getPricesRequest xmlns="http://www.GlobalBettingExchange.com/ExternalAPI/" NumberForPricesRequired="1" NumberAgainstPricesRequired="1">
            <MarketIds>9430420</MarketIds>
         </getPricesRequest>
      </ns0:GetPrices>
   </ns1:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And the response I get is:

```
DEBUG:suds.client:headers = {'SOAPAction': u'"http://www.GlobalBettingExchange.com/ExternalAPI/GetPrices"', 'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'}
DEBUG:suds.client:http succeeded: *long xml here*
```

As you can see I use headers for my username and password in every xml request. But when I get response there's no cookies in headers.

I was wondering if it's possible to somehow insert cookies into my requests or something similiar to achieve persistance. (Like using Session in RESTful services)

Comment: Never really played with soap, but what about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21587554/extracting-cookie-from-soap-response-in-suds) + [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) ?

Comment: @Arount as you can see response doesn't really return me any cookies which i could insert into next request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You are at the mercy of the server response - which I understand does not return any cookies.

A corner case for spreeding up HTTP basic auth exists, enabling preemptivly sending credentials, but does not apply.

Make sure the HTTPS connection is reused.

Comment: Yes, the server does not return any cookies. I'm using same client object to make requests to server - so I'm guessing I'm using persistent connection ?

Comment: Typically yes. So are you allowed to make parallell requests?

Comment: Ok, make sure the connection pool, if you have one, has enough connections.